# Working with Request.Files and Changing from POST to GET without reloading page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, request

I am trying to figure out if I have something wrong with my architecture, or if I am just in need of a quick fix.

I have the following on my page:

```
<div ID="UploadDashboardDecorationZone">
    <fieldset id="UploadDashboard">
        <legend>Upload Dashboard</legend>
        <telerik:RadUpload ID="UploadDashboardSelector" Runat="server" Width="235px" AllowedFileExtensions=".xml"  MaxFileInputsCount="1" ControlObjectsVisibility="None" />
    </fieldset>        
    <div class="BottomButton">
        <telerik:RadButton ID="SubmitUploadDashboardButton" Runat="Server" Text="Upload" OnClientClicked="CloseUploadDashboard" />  
    </div>
</div>
```

The user selects a file they wish to upload, then they press the SubmitUploadDashboardButton.

I then have the following server-side code:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0) HandleUploadedFile();
}
```

This all works great. The uploaded file is responded to and I see the changes on my page. The only problem is that I have left my page's request HTTP Method as POST and not GET. This means that bad things will happen if the user refreshes the page.

Previously, I had used the following code-snippet to resolve this issue:

```
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
```

Unfortunately, this does not work for me anymore. I don't want the flashing that happens with reloading the page (in addition to some code issues that arise with reloading).

What are my other options here? If I wrap `UploadDashboardDecorationZone` with an UpdatePanel, then Request.Files comes out as 0.

Is there a quick code-fix for this that is common? Or am I missing something deeper in my understanding of how the file upload process works?

Thanks.

Comment: Using DevExpress, I once read that they provide an upload method that POSTs to a hidden IFRAME and therefore is "transparent" in terms of refreshing the main page. Maybe you could configure your Telerik control in this way, too?

Comment: I will have to do some reading on this method. Thank you for the suggestion! :)

Comment: In a recent project, I successfully used the HTML 5 File API which does uploading of the files through XmlHttpRequest object (aka AJAX) which also has no full page POST). Requires modern browsers, though.

Comment: Any idea if it is supported by IE8? That's the only non-modern browser in my requirements. I'll check it out -- I'm reading a blog about it right now. From the blog's time of writing it sounds like only IE9 supports it. Shoot.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Even IE9 does not support this fully :-( See the code snippet in [my SO question for a list of supported browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772416).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to get around the "flash" when the page changes unless you do your calls using `Ajax` which doesn't require the page to reload at all.

Comment: I am OK with the flash from the button submitting. I am not OK with a second flash as I call Page.Response.Redirect. Sorry for being unclear there. :)